# Есть ли у русского языка "стандартный диалект" (с письменностью и преподаваемый в школах)?

Tags: история, диалектология

Есть ли у русского что-то похожее на то, что есть у британского английского (имеется в виду американский английский)? Есть ощущение, что то, что среднестатистический россиянин понимает под словом "диалект", — это несравнимо меньшее, чем то, что произошло с английским, когда его "увезли" на известный континент. Но я — филолог английского, не русист, могу ошибаться. Судя по Википедии, у русского попросту нет такого диалекта. Права я?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Принято говорить, что общенародный язык существует в 4 основных формах, одна из которых нормативна, остальные ненормативны - просторечия, жаргоны, территориальные диалекты.  "Стандартный диалект" в русском языке - это, скорее всего, **русский литературный язык** - образцовая, нормированная и кодифицированная форма национального языка, обладающая богатым лексическим фондом, развитой системой стилей. Он выполняет функции бытового языка грамотных людей, языка науки, публицистики, государственного управления, языка культуры, литературы, образования, средств массовой информации и т.д. Однако в определенных ситуациях функции литературного языка могут быть ограничены (например, он может функционировать в основном в письменной речи, а в устной используются территориальные диалекты). Литературный язык используется в различных сферах общественной и индивидуальной деятельности человека.

Литературный язык имеет свою историю.
В XVI веке в Московской Руси решили нормализовать письменность русского языка (тогда он назывался «проста мова» и подвергался влиянию белорусского и украинского) – ввести преобладание сочинительной связи в предложениях и частое употребление союзов «да», «и», «а». Двойственное число было утрачено, а склонение существительных стало очень похоже на современное. А **основой литературного языка стали характерные черты московской речи**. Например, «аканье», согласный «г», окончания «ово» и «ево», указательные местоимения (себя, тебя и др.). Начало книгопечатания окончательно утвердило литературный русский язык.

В Петровскую эпоху русский язык освободили от «опеки» церкви, а в 1708 году реформировали азбуку, чтобы она стала ближе к европейскому образцу.

Во второй половине XVIII века Ломоносов заложил новые нормы русского языка, объединив все, что было до этого: разговорную речь, народную поэзию и даже приказной язык. После него язык преобразовывали Державин, Радищев, Фонвизин. Именно они увеличили количество синонимов в русском языке, чтобы как следует раскрыть его богатство.

Огромный вклад в развитие нашей речи внес Пушкин, который отвергал все ограничения по стилю и комбинировал русские слова с некоторыми европейскими, чтобы создать полноценную и красочную картину русского языка. Его поддержали Лермонтов и Гоголь.

Выходит, наш современный русский язык, со всеми его лексическими и грамматическими правилами произошел **от смешения различных восточнославянских диалектов**, которые были распространены на территории всей Руси, и церковнославянского языка. И теперь **слово диалект понимается в узком смысле - местный говор в отличие от литературного языка**

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял, речь идет об американском английском, который формировался под влиянием не исключительно «британского» варианта (какой из диалектов имеется в виду?), но и той культурной (а следственно, и языковой) «смеси», которая явилась результатом объединения и активного взаимодействия разных народов. На вопрос, происходило ли что-нибудь такое с современным русским языков, ответ однозначен — нет; однако если рассматривать факты далекого прошлого, то, возможно, чем-то хоть сколько-нибудь подобным можно считать историю становления белорусского и украинского языков из древнерусского (общевосточнославянского) языка. Думаю, более подробно рассматривать их формирование нет смысла.

Считать «американиш» диалектом английского или отдельным языком, вопрос, кажется, скорее политический (да и, вообще говоря, это применимо к большинству диалектов). Вспомните известное изречение: «Язык — это диалект с армией и флотом».

Теперь о русских диалектах. Действительно, носитель русского литературного языка ясно осознает, что диалект это не вполне язык. Наверняка сразу вспомнятся деревни и села, находящиеся не в Московской области, или что-нибудь такое.

Приведу отрывок из книги В. А. Плунгяна «Почему языки такие разные»:

> У диалекта есть два главных признака. **Во-первых**, все диалекты некоторого языка, конечно, должны быть лингвистически близко родственны друг другу... На севере России встречаются деревни, в которых живут русские и карелы. Русский и карельский язык много столетий сосуществуют друг с другом как соседи, но мы никогда не скажем, что русский и карельский — диалекты одного языка. Русский язык относится к славянским, а карельский — к финно-угорским языкам <...>, и это исключает всякую возможность считать их диалектами друг друга.
>
> **Во-вторых**, диалект всегда используется говорящими не так, как «полноправный» (или «стандартный», или «литературный») язык. Если вы говорите на литературном языке, то вы можете использовать его в любой ситуации: и дома, и разговаривая с друзьями, и в школе, и на работе; тот же язык звучит по радио, используется в книгах и газетах, и т. д. В своей стране, в своем «доме» у литературного языка, как правило, нет конкурентов: этот язык может (и должен) использоваться везде, в любой сфере. <...> *Иначе используется диалект: на нем не издают газет и обычно вообще не пишут (а если начинают писать, значит, это уже, так сказать, не совсем диалект), на нем не говорят по радио (по крайней мере, обычно не говорят дикторы радио), на нем вообще редко говорят за пределами своего дома, своего села, своей местности; при этом на диалекте говорят друг с другом только жители этой местности и только когда они считают, что идет разговор «между своими».* «С чужими» или «в официальной ситуации» (назовем это так) использование диалекта сразу становится невозможно. А использование литературного языка возможно всегда. Не правда ли, отношения между диалектом и литературным языком не симметричны: одному позволено всё, а другому достается только ограниченная область применения? Лингвисты так часто и называют это явление — функциональная асимметричность (то есть неравноправие функций, сфер применения).
>
> ...Лингвисты и историки сейчас думают, что после образования Русского государства (IX–XII века) диалектов на его территории постепенно становилось меньше и они становились более похожими друг на друга. Это была «объединительная» эпоха. К концу ее язык на территории Русского государства стал более однородным. Да и сейчас, надо сказать, современный русский язык на удивление однороден — особенно если подумать о том, на какой большой территории он распространен. Русские диалекты по степени отдаленности от литературного языка нельзя даже сравнивать с итальянскими или немецкими — этими европейскими «рекордсменами» по части разнородности и раздробленности.

Думаю, это очень хорошее общее описание судеб русских диалектов.

Случаи, когда русские диалекты приобретали свою письменность (некириллическую, со своими особенностями) и преподавались в школе, мне не известны.